# Enumerate files in a folder using SSIS Script Task

Tags: ssis

Can someone please show how to enumerate files in a given folder using Script Task in SSIS?

Comment: It's not duplicate - I want do this through Script Task not through enumerating in For loop and then process the file.

Comment: There is a good use case for enumeration in a script task. We use this approach to first enumerate files and then check this list against a list of already processed files that's coming from a database. In that way we don't need to fire a separate SQL task for each and every file. The time saved makes this a very valid request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure two variables: read-only string `User::download_path` and read-write object `User::files_to_process` to receive the list of files.

```cs
public void Main()
{
    bool fireAgain = true;

    var filesToProcess = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    var filesInDirectory = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

    var download_path = (String)Dts.Variables["User::download_path"].Value;

    // Find for example all csv files in the directory which are having size > 0 
    var downloadedFiles = new DirectoryInfo(download_path).EnumerateFiles("*.csv",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (var f in downloadedFiles)
    {
        if (f.Length > 0)
            filesInDirectory.Add(f.FullName);
    }

    Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Getting files in directory", downloadedFiles.Count().ToString() + " found.", "", 0, ref fireAgain);

    // Report the file names into the SSIS Log:
    foreach (var f in filesToProcess)
    {
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, f.ToString(), "Ready for processing", "", 0, ref fireAgain);
    }

    // Return them into the READWRITE object variable
    Dts.Variables["User::files_to_process"].Value = filesInDirectory;

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: How does the setup look?

Comment: Which setup? In SSIS this is just a script task.

Comment: I tried adding the script task but it kept failing so I went directly to the expression for the connection manager and added an expression which is working fine for now. Thanks.